# Erroneous exception "A WebView method was called on thread 'WebViewCoreThread'."

Tags: android, webview

I'm having this `StackTrace` logged when trying a simple `WebView` project on the Samsung Tab 8.9

```
04-04 13:32:26.688: D/core(9992): core.cpp  228 bind    alias=User
04-04 13:32:26.708: W/webview(9992): java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'WebViewCoreThread'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.
04-04 13:32:26.708: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:14244)
04-04 13:32:26.708: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.WebView.getSettings(WebView.java:5378)
04-04 13:32:26.708: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.WebView.getVisibleTitleHeightImpl(WebView.java:2343)
04-04 13:32:26.708: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.WebView.getViewHeight(WebView.java:2385)
04-04 13:32:26.708: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore.setupViewport(WebViewCore.java:3422)
04-04 13:32:26.708: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore.didFirstLayout(WebViewCore.java:3149)
04-04 13:32:26.708: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.nativeServiceFuncPtrQueue(Native Method)
04-04 13:32:26.708: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:113)
04-04 13:32:26.708: W/webview(9992):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 13:32:26.708: W/webview(9992):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-04 13:32:26.708: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:828)
04-04 13:32:26.708: W/webview(9992):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-04 13:32:26.718: W/webview(9992): java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'WebViewCoreThread'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.
04-04 13:32:26.718: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:14244)
04-04 13:32:26.718: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.WebView.getSettings(WebView.java:5378)
04-04 13:32:26.718: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.WebView.getVisibleTitleHeightImpl(WebView.java:2343)
04-04 13:32:26.718: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.WebView.getViewHeight(WebView.java:2385)
04-04 13:32:26.718: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore.setupViewport(WebViewCore.java:3422)
04-04 13:32:26.718: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore.didFirstLayout(WebViewCore.java:3149)
04-04 13:32:26.718: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.nativeServiceFuncPtrQueue(Native Method)
04-04 13:32:26.718: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:113)
04-04 13:32:26.718: W/webview(9992):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 13:32:26.718: W/webview(9992):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-04 13:32:26.718: W/webview(9992):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:828)
04-04 13:32:26.718: W/webview(9992):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

As I understand it, the WebView is saying that I'm calling a WebView method on a WebView thread - rather than on the UI Thread. My problem is that I'm strictly *not* touching the `WebView` apart from in my `onCreate()` method - which is always run as part of the `Activity lifecycle` which AFAIK is always on the UI thread...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WebView mWebView = new WebView(this);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.htm");
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);      
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new CoreModInterface(), "Android");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    setContentView(mWebView);
}
```

This warning doesn't happen on Nexus devices. Is this a problem with the Samsung Tab 8.9?

**Edit**

Removing these two lines removes the error. Adding these two lines at the same position inside of an explicit runOnUiThread() also gives the same error. At this stage I'm believing once more Samsung have made another mistake.

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);      
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new CoreModInterface(), "Android");
```

Comment: Did you find a way finally? Because I am having exactly the same problem.